# Help reviewing new users' posts

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, review

I just want to bring your attention to [the review site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review) where you can see questions/answers posted by new users so we can assist them in getting to know the SE system and maybe improving their posts. (courtesy of [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1001/430) thread at meta.TeX)

Comment: @Tobias Why you are not a moderator? You're the most proficient guy for this work.

Comment: @mbq thanks, I had to decline [your nomination](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100/nominate-and-elect-our-temporary-moderators/111#111) due to a lack of time, but I'm actually considering this when the [community election](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-exchange-2011-elections-begin/) will take place

Comment: How would one normally get there, other than coming to this question here at meta?

Comment: @DarenW: that's the question here... this is only one of multiple special sites where no link leads to. I also don't understand why such a helpful utility is hidden so terribly good

Comment: @Tobias I await [your nomination](http://physics.stackexchange.com/election) then ;-)

Comment: @mbq: [alright then](http://physics.stackexchange.com/election#post-7791)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with these sorts of announcements, I'm just going to close it because it's not really something that can be answered, and this way it doesn't pollute our unanswered questions list.

Comment: @David no problem, this one is less relevant anyway since now there is a review link next to the chat link